# divide workload on different hardware using MPI

Tags: mpi

I have a small network with computers of different hardware. Is it possible to optimize workload division between these hardware using MPI? ie. give nodes with larger ram and better cpu more data to compute? minimizing waiting time between different nodes for final reduction.

Thanks!

Comment: This depends largely on the algorithm your processes are running. For instance, in an embarrassingly parallel master-slave system where the master issues work units to the nodes once they've completed the previous work unit, load balancing happens automatically. Other algorithms may be harder to load balance. Can you post some details about how your program works?

Comment: In my program data are divided into equal-sized batches. Each node in the network will process some of them. The result of each batch will be summed up after all batches are processed. Is this the embarrassingly-parallel case you mentioned? So there is no specific code I have to write for taking care of the workload? Sorry, just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my program data are divided into equal-sized batches. Each node in the network will process some of them. The result of each batch will be summed up after all batches are processed.

Can you divide the work into more batches than there are processes? If so, change your program so that instead of each process receiving one batch, the master keeps sending batches to whichever node is available, for as long as there are unassigned batches. It should be a fairly easy modification, and it will make faster nodes process more data, leading to a lower overall completion time. There are further enhancements you can make, e.g. once all batches have been assigned and a fast node is available, you could take an already assigned batch away from a slow node and reassign it to said fast node. But these may not be worth the extra effort.

If you absolutely have to work with as many batches as you have nodes, then you'll have to find some way of deciding which nodes are fast and which ones are slow. Perhaps the most robust way of doing this is to assign small, equally sized test batches to each process, and have them time their own solutions. The master can then divide the real data into appropriately sized batches for each node. The biggest downside to this approach is that if the initial speed measurement is inaccurate, then your efforts at load balancing may end up doing more harm than good. Also, depending on the exact data and algorithm you're working with, runtimes with small data sets may not be indicative of runtimes with large data sets.

Yet another way would be to take thorough measurements of each node's speed (i.e. multiple runs with large data sets) in advance, and have the master balance batch sizes according to this precompiled information. The obvious complication here is that you'll somehow have to keep this registry up to date and available.

All in all, I would recommend the very first approach: divide the work into many smaller chunks, and assign chunks to whichever node is available at the moment.